# responsive select menu layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im using bootstrap and I want to have in md, lg and xml screens  4 select menus next to each other horizontally and with "Search" vertically aligned with the 4 selects:

[image]

Then in smaller devices I want to have instead of 4 select menu next to each other horizontally I want to have 2 select menu above and 2 select menu below, like:

[image]

But Im not having success achieving this, do you know how to achieve that?

Working exampe: http://jsfiddle.net/wqdqfuud/

The first point is working, the 4 select menus are next to each other horizontally but the issue is that some text is hidden because the select menu size is not large enough. The other 2 points Im not having sucess to achieve them.

html:

```
<body>
  <div class="container py-4">
    <div class="row mb-3 mb-md-0">
      <div class="col">
        <h1 class="text-center d-md-none my-0 h5 text-heading-blue font-weight-bold">Search</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <h1 class="d-none d-md-block w-100 mr-auto my-0 h5 text-heading-blue font-weight-bold">Search</h1>
        <form class="mr-2">
          <select class="form-control font-weight-normal text-gray" id="">
            <option selected class="selected">Order By P1</option>
            <option>i2</option>
          </select>
        </form>
        <form class="mr-2">
          <select class="form-control font-weight-normal text-gray" id="">
            <option selected class="selected">Order By P2</option>
            <option>i1</option>
          </select>
        </form>
        <form class="mr-2">
          <select class="form-control font-weight-normal text-gray" id="">
            <option selected class="selected">Order By P3</option>
            <option>i2</option>
          </select>
        </form>
        <form>
          <select class="form-control font-weight-normal text-gray" id="">
            <option selected class="selected">Order by P4</option>
            <option>i1</option>
          </select>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're awfully close, you've just got a few things wrong with your structure that can be better achieved using the Grid framework instead of `d-flex`.  Here's how I would achieve your desired results:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
      <h1 class="text-md-center">Search</h1>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 col-md-3 mb-4 mb-md-0">
          <form>
          <select class="custom-select form-control" id="i1">
          <option selected>Order By 1</option>
          <option>i2</option>
          <option >i2</option>
          </select>
          </form>
        </div>

        <div class="col-6 col-md-3 mb-4 mb-md-0">
          <form>
          <select class="custom-select form-control" id="i2">
          <option selected>Order By 2</option>
          <option>i2</option>
          <option >i2</option>
          </select>
          </form>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-6 col-md-3">
          <form>
          <select class="custom-select form-control" id="i3">
          <option selected>Order By 3</option>
          <option>i2</option>
          <option >i2</option>
          </select>
          </form>
        </div>

        <div class="col-6 col-md-3">
          <form>
          <select class="custom-select form-control" id="i4">
          <option selected>Order By 4</option>
          <option>i2</option>
          <option >i2</option>
          </select>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
              
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And a Bootply example can be viewed here: https://www.bootply.com/6VbSYN0Rlj

This example relies on more responsive classes for things like having 'Search' align center on larger screens and left on smaller.  It also utilizes the Grid framework (with an embedded `row` to help line everything up.  Where we need to add margins between the first two `select` options and the last two there is a responsive margin class in place.

Comment: Thanks, its working. But do you know why in md, lg and xl devices the text of the select menu is hidden? It seems that is hidden because the select menu is too small, but in this large devices there is enough space so why the select menu dont adjust to show the full text?

Comment: In the above code each `<select>` takes up 100% of the column space it is allowed.  But remember; in `-md` and greater that's `col-3` in a column that is already only 50% of a fixed-width container.  You have two options there... flipping to `container-fluid` to use 100% of the viewport width, or decreasing the column for the `Search` header and increasing the width of the options wrapper column (ex. `col-md-4` for Search, `col-md-8` for forms).